# How to speedup image proxy

Tags: node.js, encryption, proxy

I have a simple Express app where I try to hide the actual url of the image by encrypting using AES 256 so the new url looks like this

```
http://example.com/img/<encrypted-string>
```

And in backend, it just decrypt the string and pipe the response from the actual url out.

```
// decrypt the string and get actualUrl
var reply = request(actualUrl)
req.pipe(reply)
reply.pipe(res)
```

The thing is it's so much slower than the actual url. Is there anyway that I can speed this process up.

Comment: Better could be to use db to store key:value pairs `{encrypted-string:'/path/to/img.jpg'}`. This way you only need to encrypt it once.

Comment: I ended up using a small nginx instance for this.